# merge two tables with partial relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by, left-join

I have some messy data in text files (2 tables). I'd like to merge it into 1 table but there are duplication issues. My data looks like the following:

*Status table*

```
+--------------------------+
| | Last Name | Status  |  |
+--------------------------+
| | Jones     | On Time |  |
| | Jones     | On Time |  |
| | Jones     | On Time |  |
| | Jones     | On Time |  |
| | Jones     | Missing |  |
| | Hoinski   | On Time |  |
| | Hoinski   | Late    |  |
| | Hoinski   | Late    |  |
| | Hoinski   | Missing |  |
+--------------------------+
```

*Risk table*

```
+-------------------------+
| | Last Name |  Risk  |  |
+-------------------------+
| | Jones     | High   |  |
| | Jones     | High   |  |
| | Jones     | Low    |  |
| | Jones     | Medium |  |
| | Jones     | Medium |  |
| | Jones     | Medium |  |
| | Jones     | Medium |  |
| | Smith     | Low    |  |
| | Smith     | Medium |  |
| | Smith     | Medium |  |
| | Smith     | Medium |  |
| | Hoinski   | High   |  |
| | Hoinski   | High   |  |
| | Hoinski   | Low    |  |
+-------------------------+
```

How can I use sql to aggregate these two tables into 1 table? Is it possible? I know I do not have a proper relationship (many to many) so it doesn't quite make sense. But what if I aggregate the data using Group By statements on the [last name] field?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Can you provide the expected result?

Comment: `mysql` and `sql-server` tags?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct `GROUP BY` will resolve your problem, here's the query.

```
    SELECT * FROM Status 
    INNER JOIN Risk ON Status.[Last Name] = Risk.[Last Name] 
    GROUP BY Status.[Last Name]
```

Comment: `Group by` may resolve the problem, but your query doesn't because you need include all 3 fields on the `group by` and replace the `select *` for the same fields.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve duplicated with `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT Distinct S.[Last Name] , S.Status, R.Risk  
FROM Status S
INNER JOIN Risk R
   ON R.[Last Name] = S.[Last Name]
```